# WPF Modal Window Transparency

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling

I have created a modal WPF window that looks as follows:

[image]

Here is the code for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="Dionysus.Core.Controls.ModalWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ModalWindow" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" WindowStyle="None">

<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.7" />
</Grid>
```

The "ErrorControl" is then added as follows:

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(uc);
```

The problem is as soon as I expand the stack trace, the controls transparency also changes:

[image]

I am assuming this has something to do with the `ScrollViewer` that uses the incorrect transparency, ie of the `Rectangle` instead of the containing `Window`.

I have also set the `Opacity` of the `UserControl` which owns the `ScrollViewer` to 1 and then binded the `Opacity`:

```
<ScrollViewer Background="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Opacity}">
```

Can anyone help me?

--

UPDATE

Here is the code for the `UserControl` that is inserted into the `Window`

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRootx" Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" Text="An error has occured:" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Medium"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,10,5,5" Text="{Binding Error}"/>
            <odc:OdcExpander Header="Stack Trace" Margin="5" IsExpanded="False" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StackTrace}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,10,5,5" IsReadOnly="True" MaxHeight="370"/>
            </odc:OdcExpander>
            <odc:OdcExpander Header="Comment" Margin="5" IsExpanded="False">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Comment}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,10,5,5" MaxHeight="370" Name="txtComment"/>
            </odc:OdcExpander>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,10,5,5" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource DionysusButton}"  Width="100" Height="23" IsDefault="True" Name="btnSendError">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Dionysus.Shell;component/Images/camera-icon.png" Margin="0,0,5,0">

                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="Send to IT" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <core:DionysusTriggerAction Height="0" Width="0" TargetControl="{Binding ElementName=btnSendError}" MethodName="SendError"></core:DionysusTriggerAction>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource DionysusButton}"  Width="100" Height="23" Name="btnExit" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsCancel="True">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Dionysus.Shell;component/Images/DeleteRed.png" Margin="0,0,5,0">

                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="Close" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <core:DionysusTriggerAction Height="0" Name="triggerAction2" Width="0" TargetControl="{Binding ElementName=btnExit}" MethodName="Exit"></core:DionysusTriggerAction>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your window has a fixed size and cannot be resized, you can use the following trick:

```
<Grid>
    <Border BorderThickness="100" BorderBrush="Gray" Opacity="0.7">
        <Grid Background="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="contentPlaceHolder">
            <TextBlock  Text="HELLO WORLD" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

However, it is unlikely that your Window will always have the same size, so to make it more dynamic, you could change the layout of the Window as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="YourDesiredSize"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="YourDesiredSize"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.7" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0.7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" x:Name="contentPlaceHolder">
        <TextBlock  Text="HELLO WORLD" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The result of this window placed on top of another looks more or less like this:

[image: transparent scrollviewer]

and then instead of adding to the `MainGrid`, add the UserControl to the `contentPlaceHolder` or however you want to call it:

```
contentPlaceHolder.Children.Add(uc);
```

Comment: Hi, I changed my code accordingly and the problem still remains that my actual `UserControl` is still transparent!

Comment: Try inserting a `ScrollViewer` into your `contentPlaceHolder`, if I'm not mistaken it should do the same!

Comment: I tried it, and it is still not transparent. I've updated the screenshot. Is there anything else in your code (I'm thinking `ElementBinding` or `DataTemplates`) which might cause the background to change as soon as the `Expander` opens?

Comment: I have updated my question with code for my user control, you can have a look there!

Comment: Nothing unusual there as far as I can see. What is the `odc:OdcExpander`? Like I said, I get the feeling it has something to do with that element (transparency appears when expander is opened)

Comment: I see its only a problem when it is expanded, and only the control within the odc:OdcExpander is transparent. OdcExpander is a part of the `Oddysey WPF Controls` suite.

Comment: I've entirely removed the expanders now, it is only the `Textbox` on the control! And the problem remains.

Comment: then the problem must be somewhere else, maybe a trigger or binding somehwere?

Comment: Nothing that I can see, I have no styles for the `Expander` so it is standard. And even if I change the background of the `Expander` and `TextBox` it is still transparent!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a solution that works for me, I'm sure it's not the best but it might help someone having the same problem as I did.

The problem was that controls within my `UserControl` that I added to my `Window` were transparent, although I could not figure out the reason, I found a simple workaround.

By changing the `OpacityMask` property of the `UserControl` to whatever the required `Background` colour is, even if the controls opacity changes, it will be masked with the `Brush` that you supply.

```
uc.OpacityMask = Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
```

Hope it helps someone!